# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have mastered python, html, css and i wanted to start learning React. I am totally new to React, i am trying to create a messeging website. I keep getting [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/layIk.png). I dont understand why i am getting this error, ive tried everything including starting all over again and i keep getting the exact same error.

[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEVms.png)

[index.js - This is where i am getting the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUA4x.png)

[app.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZpLQ.png)

I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJzbJQLGehs

I followed exactly all the steps he did. I did some research and tried a couple of things but none work. Does someone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Your file is not named `App.js` but `App,.jsx`. It has a stray `,` in there. Rename the file to remove the comma and it should work.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can *edit* your question and replace the images with properly formatted text. See: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your App.jsx file name is App,.jsx thats why it is giving that error.
Rename your file with App.jsx and you are good to go